# How to smooth the transition between css keyframes

Tags: css, sass

I have the following code for an image of a  plane to come in from the left hand side of the page, land... ride on straight for 800px then take off again off the opposite side of the page.

But what is getting to me is the jerkiness between each percentage.

is there a away for it to smooth out the transitions between keyframes.

```
@keyframes plane-right {


    0% {
        visibility:visible;
        transform: translate(-2000px, -400px) rotate(-20deg) scaleX(-1);

    }
    40% {
        visibility:visible;
        transform: translate(-400px, -0px) rotate(-0deg) scaleX(-1);
    }
    60% {
        visibility:visible;
        transform: translate(400px, -0px) rotate(-5deg) scaleX(-1);
    }

    100% {
        visibility:visible;
        transform: translate(2000px, -400px) rotate(-40deg) scaleX(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add animation duration and animation timing-function to control the length of the animation and the timing (smoothness).

```css
.plane-right-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #bada55;
  border-radius: 5px;
  animation-name: plane-right;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}

@keyframes plane-right {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translate(-2000px, -400px) rotate(-20deg) scaleX(-1);
  }
  40% {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translate(-400px, -0px) rotate(-0deg) scaleX(-1);
  }
  60% {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translate(400px, -0px) rotate(-5deg) scaleX(-1);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translate(2000px, -400px) rotate(-40deg) scaleX(-1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="plane-right-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following animation-timing property to your image tag, this will help

```
transform-origin:50px 5px;
transition:transform 1s ease-in-out 0s;
animation-duration: 2.2s;
animation-name: paragato;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;    
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Sumit, I am quite new to CSS animations and don't quite understand how to apply your solution?

Comment: If you can provide me the HTML of your page then i can modify this for you.

Comment: I have managed to sort it thanks, your answer kind of got me thinking of another way to do it.

Comment: I am geld that my answer helped you. :)